# How to force Windows to call the partition it installs on C:?

Tags: windows-xp, installation, drive-letter

I'm going to install Windows XP from a CD and want to make sure it calls the partition it lands on `C:`. The target partition is the first one on a SATA disk, which is not the first one in my computer. There's no IDE disk there.

I don't think I can swap the disks, as I'm using a fake RAID and really don't want to get problems with it. The target partition is on a normal disk.

I know it may be [unimportant](https://superuser.com/questions/15568/is-keeping-the-primary-hard-disk-as-disk-c-still-relevant), but I don't want to run in any problems I can avoid. I've seen a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/216143/change-drive-letter-from-d-to-c-for-windows-drive) slightly related to it, but I'm not going to install from a USB.

Comment: Its always wise to disconnect all but the target drive prior to a XP install.

Answer (score 0):

If you install from a CD, it should land on C: by default. Just pick the hard drive, even if it's a RAID system (should just see the RAID in the installer), and you're good to go. The only time I've ever seen it pick D: is when installing from a flash drive (because then the drive takes C, so D is the next letter up).

Comment: I've seen issues when you have a card reader installed.  It will install xp on another drive letter.  The solution to that is to just unplug the reader during the partitioning phase.

Comment: It's not true, I tried it and Windows calls it's installation partition `I:`. I really do hate it.